# Python threading vs. process for creating a timer function

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I would like to run a definition in the background, and pass an argument into it (how long it should run for), but the following code isn't working:

```
thread = threading.Thread(target= run_timer, args=timer_time_value) #  Where timer_time_value is taken from user input, and converted into an integer.
thread.daemon = True
thread.start()

def run_timer(time_to_sleep_For):
    time_to_sleep_For = int(time_to_sleep_For)
    time.sleep(time_to_sleep_For)
    Speak("Timer done!")
```

If I use process, I replace the first chunk of code with:

```
p = Process(target= run_timer, args=timer_time_value)
p.start()
p.join()
```

However, both return:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

My question is, which module should I use, and what is the correct way to set it up?

Comment: `args` expects an iterable. Pass as `args=(timer_time_value,)` i.e. a tuple with 1 item in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @roganjosh pointed out you need to pass a list or a tuple (see [Thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread)). This is working example:

```
import threading    
import time

def run_timer(time_to_sleep_for):
  time.sleep(time_to_sleep_for)
  print("Timer done!")


user_time = "3"

try:
  user_time = int(user_time)
except ValueError:
  user_time = 0  # default sleep

thread = threading.Thread(target=run_timer,
                          args=(user_time,))
thread.daemon = True
thread.start()
thread.join()
```

For the differences between processes and threads see [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580/multiprocessing-vs-threading-python).

BTW: It is maybe better to parse the user input outside the thread as shown in the example.

Comment: @roganjosh: Thanks for your initial comment. Glad I could help.